# ASP.NET Core MVC: How to change QueryString param into "pretty" URL param?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My issue is an aesthetic one. I have the following Controller:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{EmployeeTypeID:int?}")]
public IActionResult FilterByType(int EmployeeTypeID = 1)
{ ... }
```

Which is called when I go to the following routes, for example:

```
/Employees/FilterByType
/Employees/FilterByType/2
```

Great. The controller returns the following ViewModel to the View:

```
public class EmployeesByTypeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> FilteredEmployees { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeTypes { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

And my view, has a dropdown that **should** change the URL param (in order to filter by a different EmployeeType):

```
@model Tiendas.Models.EmployeesByTypeViewModel  
<h2>Employees</h2>
<form asp-controller="Employees" asp-action="FilterByType" method="GET">
    <select asp-for="EmployeeTypeID" asp-items="Model.EmployeeTypes">
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>
//code displaying filtered employees...
```

However, when I'm at `/Employees/FilterByType` and I submit the form it results in, for example:

```
/Employees/FilterByType?EmployeeTypeID=3
```

instead of:

```
/Employees/FilterByType/3
```

Which is what I want (functionality wise both work). Additionally, if I type the URL above and then submit the form, I get the following:

```
/Employees/FilterByType/3?EmployeeTypeID=1
```

How can I get a *pretty* URL param instead of the QueryString? I'm using attribute routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form that is making a GET. The browser has no knowledge of your route definition and in accordance with the standards, the value of any form controls are added as query string values.

If you want to generate `/Employees/FilterByType/3`, then you will need javascript/jquery to generate the url, and `location.href` to make the redirect, for example

```cs
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the default action
    baseUrl = '@Url.Action("FilterByType", "Employees")';
    var selectedEmployee = $('#EmployeeTypeID').val();
    location.href = baseUrl + '/' + selectedEmployee; // redirect
});
```