# How to use the value attribute in <a> in <a> href as parameter to Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5.1

This is my  link inside modal

```
    <a id="modalRelease" value="" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="@Url.Action("GoToReleaseNotes", "CoreTRac", new {path = @"C:\Gowresh\C# training\Assignment\CoreTrac Version Details\CoreTrac Version Details\Resources\Release\3.76 HFA.pdf"})">Release Note </a>
```

As you can see the value is empty as I am setting the value from JS as below

```
 var releaseNote = e.relatedTarget.dataset.param3;
        $("#modalRelease").val(releaseNote);
```

So I am expecting the  link to call a Controller action method by changing the parameter each time i.e

```
new {path = "How to read the value attribute and assign here "}
```

But for now I have hardcoded the path, I need it to be as the value attribute which I am setting from JS. tried many things but no help

Comment: You need to build the url (the `href` attribute) using javascript

Comment: Tried that, it opens a blank modal poupup

Comment: Tried what? We cannot guess your code!

Comment: I have added JS scipt to read the value attribute and assign it to href but it says the "route" does not exist in the context. it might be silly i am newbie 
          var route = document.getElementById("modalRelease").val;
            var a = document.getElementById("modalRelease"); //or grab it by tagname etc
            a.href = "@Url.Action("GoToReleaseNotes", "CoreTRac", new {path = route })"

Comment: Edit your question (and that code throws an exception! `Url.Action()` is server side code and `route` is a javascript variable)

Comment: You got my question right. I have link <a id="modalRelease" value="" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="@Url.Action("GoToReleaseNotes", "CoreTRac", new {path = (here i need my dynamic value which is inside the val attribute"})">Release Note </a> Finding the way to set it there tried many ways but wasnt succesful

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441537/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-change-querystring-param-into-pretty-url-param/49443055#49443055) for an example of how to build the url

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. i think i am close to the answer but now i get "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)." this error should find a way to fix this :)

Comment: The "value" attribute is non-standard for <a> tags and means nothing much, you can get it using `$("#modalRelease").attr(value)`, therefore you can also set it using `$("#modalRelease").attr(value,theValue)`. Why is `href` not considered